# how to change top-level `www` directory in cordova

Tags: angularjs, cordova, mobile, directory

I'm currently developing an AngularJS project with Cordova. For my AngularJS project, I'd like to have a directory called `src/app` at the root of the project that contains `index.html` and all of my application modules. However, Cordova expects a `www` directory instead. How can I tell Cordova to look in `src/app`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer was to simply build everything to `www`, which is the directory that cordova expects, which means all processed js/css goes there, and you have to copy any images, fonts, html, etc. as well as part of your build/watch processes.